# Android Unique CheckSum based on a list of objects

Tags: java, android

I got a list of contacts that I fetch from my device, something like:

```
public class Contact{
  String id;
  List<String> phones;

  // rest of the stuff
}
```

I want to create a checksum for all contacts that I have based on their id & phones, so i could compare in the future if my contacts have changed or not. How I can achieve this in Android in a more elegant and better way ?

Answer (score 0):

Well one easy but ugly way would be to override the toString() method of your Contact class and put together some unique value based on its attributes. Like this for example.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
char separator = ';';
for(String phone : phones){
  builder.append(phone.hashCode()).append(separator);
}
builder.append(id.hashCode());
String uniqueValue = builder.toString();
```

Then after creating or loading the Contact, save the value returned by its toString() value into some cache. Once you want to know if it changed, call the toString() again and compare the returned value with the cached value. If equal it didn't change, if not it changed.

A nicer way would be to use flags in all of its setters and getters.

```
public class SomeClass{

  private String id;
  private boolean hasChanges;

  public void setId(String pId){
    this.id = pId;
    hasChanges = true;
  }

  public boolean hasChanges(){
    return this.hasChanges;
  }

  public void commit(){
    hasChanges = false;
  }
}
```

But using this for attributes with a collection or array type is a pain in the ass. Because instead of creating getters and setters for the list, you need to map the add and remove methods your self. Therefore its a nice and efficient way. Once you accept the current version as valid you call commit() to be able to see if it changed from this state on.